# How to calculate the percentage of contribution from each contributor to words the Code in the Git or Gerrit?

Tags: git, commit, gerrit

scenario is ... 
imagine a project development is going on, and lot of contributors are adding and editing the code...
By making use commits and reviews,how to get number of line added and deleted to/from the code from each contributor and each commits?. Based on this how to calculate the percentage of contribution to words the code from each individuals?.

Comment: Git extras is doing something similar: https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/Commands.md#git-summary

Answer (score 6):

You can do this by looping through the users and using the `--shortstat` option from [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

To get all **commit** email addresses from everyone who commited run the following command:

```
git log --pretty="%ce%n" | sort | uniq
```

This will print out all email addresses, sort them, and make a unique list from this.
This can then be set to a variabele to  loop through them to get the number of commits, additions, deletions with the following script:

```
git log --author=$USER --shortstat $BRANCH | \
awk '/^ [0-9]/ { f += $1; i += $4; d += $6 } \
END { printf("%d files changed, %d insertions(+), %d deletions(-)", f, i, d) }'
```

The complete script will be like this:

```
# Loop through users
for user in $(git log --pretty="%ce%n" | sort | uniq);
do
   # print user email
   echo "$user"
   # print total files changed, total insertions, total deletions
   echo $(git log --author="${user}" --shortstat 'master' | awk '/^ [0-9]/ { f += $1; i += $4; d += $6 } END { printf("%d files changed, %d insertions(+), %d deletions(-)", f, i, d) }')
done
```

The above script will output the stats from the **master** branch.

## Example

I've checked out (`git clone https://github.com/MunGell/awesome-for-beginners`) a rather [small repository](https://github.com/MunGell/awesome-for-beginners) created a file `script.sh` and made it runnable with `chmod +x script`. When running the script it gives me the following output:

Obviscated the emails...

```
user1@gmail.com
2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
user2@users.noreply.github.com
22 files changed, 45 insertions(+), 28 deletions(-)
user3.amalik07@gmail.com
1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
user4@iastate.edu
2 files changed, 5 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
user5@gmail.com
1 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 3 deletions(-)
user6@mozilla.com
2 files changed, 8 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
user7@domain.co
1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
user8@domain.com
1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
user9@domain.me
1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
user10@perguth.de
1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
user11@gmail.com
1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
user12@mozilla.com
0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
user13@gmail.com
1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
user14@github.com
0 files changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
user15@gmail.com
1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
user16@umich.edu
1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
user17@up-nxt.com
2 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
user18@hotmail.com
1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
user19@mozilla.com
2 files changed, 52 insertions(+), 52 deletions(-)
user20@gmail.com
8 files changed, 83 insertions(+), 8 deletions(-)
user21@gmail.com
3 files changed, 3 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
user22@gmail.com
1 files changed, 4 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
user23@talater.com
1 files changed, 1 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
user24@gmail.com
4 files changed, 5 insertions(+), 1 deletions(-)
```

Comment: can you demonstrate  with one example.

Comment: i gave you one example

Comment: thank you , can i get the code in python

Comment: one more thing. I am getting the number of lines added and deleted in git. AND i would like to find the number or lines changed(added and deleted) from from each individual in Gerrit. why because in git it gives the final edited lines from each individual. Some one who is

Comment: Some one who has added 5 lines ,deleted 3 lines and then added 4 lines while working . if we apply the above code i get result as 6 insertions and 3 deletions. So it is better to track the changes and then compare.... i hope u get my point(i may not explained in proper).....                       how  can i achieve this through Gerrit.

Comment: > can i get the code in python?
I don't know python so nope. You can easily call a bash script from python to run, so i'd suggest doing that.
As for the result it is correct: add 5 lines - 3 lines = 2 lines. Then add 4 lines to it results in 6 insertions and 3 deletions.
If you want the total sum of changes do add Additions + Deletions, there's your total.

I don't know gerrit so i have no idea.

Comment: I gave you the tools, but if you don't know how to use them i suggest looking up a tutorial or so. The problem stated above is solved and gives what's being asked for. How you want to interpret that result is up to you